# LAF java works different for root

Tags: java, ubuntu, look-and-feel

I'm having problems with Look and Feel of java in Ubuntu. When I run the app it uses GTK (which is good), but when I use sudo the LAF is Metal (which is bad).

SO, how I avoid that behavior? I mean, change the default sudo LAF or something like that because the UIManager from java is not working.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: I have to add, i'm using openjdk instead of sun's jdk. Maybe someone knows a bug or something about it

Answer (score 0):

This is **(maybe)** because of the theme for root isn't the same.

Try to change the theme by starting the appereance manager as sudo:

```
sudo gnome-appearance-properties
```

Comment: Nope, There is nothing to do with gnome-appearance. I checked just in case, but root and custom are using the same

Answer (score 0):

You could either [set the Look And Feel at Runtime](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic), [set it at command-line](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#commandLine), or you could [modify swing.properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#properties)

Comment: I already try all these. It still uses the System configuration, I mean the default LAF. I did a test, printing supported LAF, default LAF and assigned LAF and that's how i know sudo LAF is diferent to normal.

Comment: @RDAM hmm, ok. I'll try a little harder to get to the bottom of this :-)

Comment: Thanks, I've see in other posts something about files which are not available for all users but still without a concrete answer. I'll update openjdk version just in case is a bug. I let you know if a get into the answer.